# Current render video card

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, opengl, directx

I want to grab information about currently running video card.
Basically my question is how to get device id from openGL string GL_RENDERER.

I'm on windows.

I have used directx function GetAdapterIdentifier([qt usage example see GpuDescription::detect()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsopengltester.cpp.html#_ZN14GpuDescription6detectEv)). It worked fine for Nvidia. If I manually switch video card for my application D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 has correct deviceID. But this approach fail when I used amd radeon. D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 contains information only for my integrated video card(even after change). But OpenGL string(GL_RENDERER) detect video card configuration for my app correctly.

Therefore how to safely get deviceid from GL_RENDERER? Having deviceid then I can get any information I want. But the problem is GL_RENDERER is a string and I can`t match it with any other system string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Win32 function called `EnumDisplayDevicesA`. Using it, you can get list of all display devices with their names and current states stored in instance of `DISPLAY_DEVICEA` structure. Then, after user selects which one GPU to use, you can create device context specifily for this GPU via `CreateDCA` call. If this function succeeds, you can continue with creating OpenGL context via `wglCreateContext`(but before you should set pixel format and so on, you can read more abour creating OpenGL context [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)).

Hope that helped you.